# How would one be able to use a variable, which is inside a for loop, outside of that for loop?

Tags: java, blackjack

I am trying to code the card game blackjack.  The idea is for me to play against a bot who is counting cards.  Firstly, I have to create the game.  In that game, there is a betting system.  The bet is taken before the hand, but the bet can be modified during the play.  When I conduct user input to ask the for the bet, I do this in a *for loop.* This is the code for the defining of the bet!

```
    double money = 100.00;
    System.out.println("You have $" +money +"0. How much would you like to bet?  ");
    double bet = scanner1.nextDouble();
    double nmoney = money - bet;

    
    if(nmoney < 0) {
        System.out.println("You do not have enough money");
    } else {
    System.out.print("You now have $");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", nmoney);

    }
```

I would like to re-use the variable "bet" again.  (The following is done in the case of a *Double Down.*  The bet is doubled, and the player only gets one card.)  The following code is that section.

```
        char move = scanner1.next().charAt(0);
        if(move == 'H' || move == 'h') {
            String p2 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
            list.remove(p2);
            cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Player gets " +p2);
        }
        if(move == 'S' || move == 's') {
        //  break;
        }
        if(move == 'D' || move == 'd') {
            bet = bet * 2;
            nmoney = nmoney - bet;
            String d1 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
            list.remove(d1);
            cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Player gets " +d1);
            
            
            //break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i--) {
            if(move == 'D' || move == 'd') {
                break;
            }
            if(move == 'S' || move == 's') {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Would you like to hit(H), or Stand(S)");
            char move2 = scanner1.next().charAt(0);
            if(move2 == 'H' || move2 == 'h') {
                String p3 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
                list.remove(p3);
                cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
                System.out.println("Player gets " +p3);
            }
            
            if(move2 == 'S' || move == 's') {
                break;
            }
```

My Question is: How could I re-use the variable *bet* outside of that for loop, or how can I redo the code to allow bet to be use again?

Thank You!

```
import java.util.*;
public class CardPlayer {

    
        
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] cards = {
                "Ace of Spades", "Two of Spades","Three of Spades","Four of Spades", "Five of Spades", "Six of Spades", "Seven of Spades", "Eight of Spades", "Nine of Spades", "Ten of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades",
                "Ace of Hearts", "Two of Hearts", "Three of Hearts", "Four of Hearts", "Five of Hearts", "Six of Hearts", "Seven of Hearts", "Eight of Hearts", "Nine of Hearts", "Ten of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts",
                "Ace of Clubs", "Two of Clubs", "Three of Clubs", "Four of Clubs", "Five of Clubs", "Six of Clubs", "Seven of Clubs", "Eight of Clubs", "Nine of Clubs", "Ten of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs",
                "Ace of Diamonds", "Two of Diamonds", "Three of Diamonds", "Four of Diamonds", "Five of Diamonds", "Six of Diamonds", "Seven of Diamonds", "Eight of Diamonds", "Nine of Diamonds", "Ten of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds",
        };  

        double money = 100.00;
        
        
        System.out.println("You have $" +money +"0. How much would you like to bet?  ");
        double bet = scanner1.nextDouble();
        double nmoney = money - bet;
    
        
        if(nmoney < 0) {
            System.out.println("You do not have enough money");
        } else {
        System.out.print("You now have $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", nmoney);
    //  break;
        }
        
        
        String Pldf1 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cards));
        list.remove(Pldf1);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        String Pldf2 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        
        list.remove(Pldf2);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        String Codf1 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        
        list.remove(Codf1);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        String Codf2 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        
        list.remove(Codf2);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        String Dddf0 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        
        list.remove(Dddf0);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        String Dudf0 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
        
        list.remove(Dudf0);
        cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        

        
        System.out.println("\nPlayer Gets            Computer Gets");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Pldf1 +"\t       " +Codf1);
        System.out.println(Pldf2 +"\t       "  +Codf2);
        System.out.println("      Dealer Gets "  +Dudf0);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Would you like to hit(H), Stand(S), or Double Down (D)");
        char move = scanner1.next().charAt(0);
        if(move == 'H' || move == 'h') {
            String p2 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
            list.remove(p2);
            cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Player gets " +p2);
        }
        if(move == 'S' || move == 's') {
        //  break;
        }
        if(move == 'D' || move == 'd') {
            bet = bet * 2;
            nmoney = nmoney - bet;
            String d1 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
            list.remove(d1);
            cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Player gets " +d1);
            
            
            //break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i--) {
            if(move == 'D' || move == 'd') {
                break;
            }
            if(move == 'S' || move == 's') {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Would you like to hit(H), or Stand(S)");
            char move2 = scanner1.next().charAt(0);
            if(move2 == 'H' || move2 == 'h') {
                String p3 = cards[(int)(Math.random()*cards.length)];
                list.remove(p3);
                cards = list.toArray(new String[0]);
                System.out.println("Player gets " +p3);
            }
            
            if(move2 == 'S' || move == 's') {
                break;
            }
            
        }
            
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not being snarky, but you would probably be better off scrapping all that code and re-think your program using methods and classes. There is no sense trying to add good code to bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need to define the variable outside the loop. Defining it outside the loop won't stop you from using it like normal inside the loop.

```java
while (condition) {
   int data = something;
   
   // do stuff
}

// Fails because data is now out of scope.
useData(data);
```

You can then change it into something like this where you define `data` before the loop starts so it can be used afterwards.

```java
// Define the variable outside the loop
int data = 0;

while (condition) {
   // re-assign value instead of creating new variable
   data = something;
   
   // do stuff
}

// Succeeds since data is still within scope
useData(data);
```